# npm live-server not auto-reloading

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have tried to work on the live server, installed a node package called `live-server` by using this command: `npm install -g live-server`

It worked fine, installed successfully and run `live-server` by `live-server` command.

Whenever I change my code and save on code editor, the browser won't refresh automatically.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
"name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Abul Khoyer",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Have you added .live-server.json file?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem as you and managed to get it working by making sure that the .html-file was properly formatted. I.e. like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Script tester!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition, any element you create should also adhere to the "correct" html formatting. It doesn't seem to like a self-closing tag like <hr/> or <br/>.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code:
for

**Usage from node**

Example:

```
var liveServer = require("live-server");

var params = {
    port: 8181, // Set the server port. Defaults to 8080.
    host: "0.0.0.0", // Set the address to bind to. Defaults to 0.0.0.0 or process.env.IP.
    root: "/public", // Set root directory that's being served. Defaults to cwd.
    open: false, // When false, it won't load your browser by default.
    ignore: 'scss,my/templates', // comma-separated string for paths to ignore
    file: "index.html", // When set, serve this file for every 404 (useful for single-page applications)
    wait: 1000, // Waits for all changes, before reloading. Defaults to 0 sec.
    mount: [['/components', './node_modules']], // Mount a directory to a route.
    logLevel: 2, // 0 = errors only, 1 = some, 2 = lots
    middleware: [function(req, res, next) { next(); }] // Takes an array of Connect-compatible middleware that are injected into the server middleware stack
};
liveServer.start(params);
```

Or else you can add a file **.live-server.json** :

If that exists it will be loaded and used as default options for live-server on the command line.

For more details see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

Comment: thanks, but I have tried this way. still not working.

Comment: app.js is blank. only `console.log("hello world");` because I'm just testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use NPM To Install A Package Called PM2.

NPM is a package manager that you will use to install frameworks and libraries to use with your Node.js applications. NPM was installed with Node.js. PM2 is a sweet little tool that is going to solve two problems for you:

1. It is going to keep your site up by restarting the application if it crashes. These crashes should NOT happen, but it is good know that PM2 has your back. (Some people may be aware of Forever.js, another tool that is used to keep node based sites running - I think you will find that PM2 has a lot to offer.)
2. It is going to help you by restarting your node application as a service every time you restart the server. Some of use know of other ways to do this, but pm2 makes it easier, and it has some added flexibility.

Install PM2 by typing thr following at the command line:

```
sudo npm install pm2 -g
```

You can follow this line to setup Nodejs production environment:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Windows 10 like myself, it's likely that your directory name is too long like this:

> C:\Users\Del\Documents\Web Development Works\JS
>   Exercises[books]\Learning JavaScript\lj

Just try to move your directory to Desktop so it will be much shorter like this:

> C:\Users\Del\Desktop\lj

In my case, the auto-reload of live-server is working after I move my directory to Desktop

Comment: That's wrong. Because when you publish your project to host, there is no *Desktop* location.

Answer (score 0):

Check your script tag in html file.
don't close your  tag as empty element like this < /> .
This was preventing my browser to load page automatically.
close it properly <> .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I solve that with check two items :

First, check your script tag in your HTML file !

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

if you try first step and it dosen't work again, move(copy/cut) your project's file in "DESKTOP", close Browser, VScode work space (command+K+F) and VScode (command+Q), and try again !